# If the earth suddenly had a new axis of rotation, would the tendency be for it’s new axis to align itself perpendicularly to its orbit over time?

Tags: axial-tilt

If the earth suddenly had a new axis of rotation (due to catastrophic events - humor me), would the tendency be for it’s new axis to align itself perpendicularly to its orbital plane over time?  For example, would the earth tend to revert to having similar "seasons" as before?  What I mean by new axis of rotation is that the poles would be in new geographical locations. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Basic Research question

Comment: I'd suggest reading [Wikipedia's page on Axial Tilt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt) and rethinking the question.

Comment: This article sort of explains what I'm looking for: https://www.inverse.com/article/23062-earth-moon-history-axis-tilt In fact, the cataclysmic event I'm imagining would ideally form another "moon".  But I don't really understand how the slowing of the earth's rotation and the moon moving away from the earth and the "righting of the earth's axis" are related.  The Wikipedia page on Axial Tilt doesn't seem to address the forces that cause or influence axial tilt which is why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 11):

### [Uranus says no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus#Axial_tilt)

More specifically, Uranus has an axial tilt of 97.77°, whereas Earth has a tilt of about 23.44°

So, if your premise ("would the tendency be for it’s new axis to align itself perpendicularly to its orbital plane over time") was true, then Uranus would already have aligned itself by now.

Comment: As would Earth.  Planets should generally form with low axial tilt -- but impacts late in the process can turn them over (Uranus), or even reverse rotation (Venus).

Comment: Thank you.  This is very helpful.